# curl with POST method working, but fetch API return error 503

Tags: fetch-api

I have to access a private API (one of Air France flight company's API), and in order to use any of their API, I need an access token.
So [in their guide](https://developer.airfranceklm.com/developer_boot_camp), they say we need to use this cURL to get the token :

`$ curl https://www.klm.com/oauthcust/oauth/token -d 'grant_type=client_credentials' -u fakeKey:fakeSecret`

#### TERMINAL

When I execute this cURL in my terminal, and replace the `fakeKey` and `fakeSecret` (which I can't give you here unfortunately) by my own, it's working well and I got this answer (with a proper token in  place of  :

```
{
  "access_token": <TOKEN>,
  "token_type":"bearer",
  "expires_in":3600
}
```

#### POSTMAN

When I do it in Postman, here is what I fill :

- URL:

  - POST: https://www.klm.com/oauthcust/oauth/token
- Authorization:

  - type: Basic Auth
  - Username: my secret Username
  - Password: my secret password
- Headers:

  - Authorization: automatically generated from my username and password
  - Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
- Body

  - checked x-www-form-urlencoded
  - grant_type: client_credentials

That's all, and when I click on `SEND`, I got my answer and my token.

#### FETCH / AXIOS / HTTPRequest

So as I am not so good yet in fetching data, I used https://kigiri.github.io/fetch/ to translate from my cURL to a `fetch` JS method. It return me this code :

```
fetch("https://www.klm.com/oauthcust/oauth/token", {
  body: "grant_type=client_credentials",
  headers: {
    Authorization: "Basic <HASH_COMPILED_FROM_USERNAME_PASSWORD>",
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
  },
  method: "POST"
})
```

The `<HASH_COMPILED_FROM_USERNAME_PASSWORD>` is exactly the same as the one Postman compiled.
So this fetch seems OK for me, however on Chrome it returns a `Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 503.`

Opera is returning me `Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin <MY_WEBSITE> is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 503.`

However it seems weird that the mistake come from their site, I think it's more something that I missed in my fetch request. Do you have an idea ?

Thanks !

Comment: Try instead `curl -i -X OPTIONS https://www.klm.com/oauthcust/oauth/token -d 'grant_type=client_credentials' -u fakeKey:fakeSecret` and you will get the same 503 response even from `curl`. The reason is: you’re adding an Authorization header to the request, and that triggers your browser to automatically on its own send a CORS preflight OPTIONS request to that server before even trying the POST request from your code. And that preflight fails — because the status of the response to that OPTIONS request is 503 instead of 200 OK. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Comment: So the gist of it is: the only way you’ll be able to successfully use that https://www.klm.com/oauthcust/oauth/token endpoint from your frontend JavaScript code is if the maintainers of that server fix it so that it doesn’t respond to OPTIONS requests with a 503. Or alternatively, if that server provides a way to authenticate without needing to send the Authorization header — for example, by instead allowing you to included the credentials as a parameter in the body of that POST — then your request won’t trigger browsers to do the preflight OPTIONS request.

Comment: and how would be the keys of the parameters ? `username` & `password` ?

Comment: I don’t know what the parameters would be or even if they actually support any such parameters on that API. I guess you would need to contact the API owners and find out. But yeah, the 503 is because of the server settings on that server. So unless they provide some other mechanism to authenticate, there’s no way to change your request that will prevent that 503.

Comment: great, thanks for those explanations. I read also https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/ to understand a bit more what is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the answer finally has been : the request must come from a back-end, otherwise the response won't have anything inside it (or error 503). Thanks @sideshowbarker to your well explaining comments !