# API Post with parameters return 503 error

Tags: c#, api, post

I sending requests to an API which was recently updated. All GET requests work perfectly but POST requests with parameters return a 503 error with about 20s timeout. POST requests without parameter work fine and POST requests using Postman work fine. It look to me like there is something with the request.ContentLength as each time I try to change the code to calculate the size the request fails immediately.

```
    HttpWebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create("https://myAPIURL") as HttpWebRequest;
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(APIUsername, APIPassword);
    request.PreAuthenticate = true;
    string param = "name=Test&description=MyDescription";
    byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(param);
    request.ContentLength = dataStream.Length;
    
    try {
      using (Stream stOut = request.GetRequestStream())
      {
        stOut.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
      }
      using (HttpWebResponse resp = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
      {
      // Do some stuff
      }
    }
    catch (WebException wex)
    {
    // catch error HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable
    }
```

The code is inspired from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/how-to-send-data-using-the-webrequest-class

I have tried:

1. Removing the request.ContentLength
2. Copying the Postman contentlenght value which is slightly higher
3. Compare the Postman and my code request using Fiddler
4. Search for similar qestions such as [curl with POST method working, but fetch API return error 503](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50522710/curl-with-post-method-working-but-fetch-api-return-error-503)

Comment: HTTP status code 503 means Service Unavailable. This is usually some problem with the server, although given that other requests work fine, it sounds like the API is misusing HTTP Status Codes. Your best bet is report the problem to the owner/maintainer of the API or it's developers to figure out whether you're making an improper request or there's some other issue.

Comment: [Link to 503 HTTP status documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/503)

Comment: Thanks but the 503 is not really relevant as the service is available and replies 100% correctly to Postman POST request with the same parameters.

Comment: May be it's a CORS issue that is being mis-reported. You're likely going to have to contact the API owners to figure this one out though, unless there's anymore information in the body of the 503 response.

Comment: Thanks. I would eliminate any CORS related issue as the postman request works perfectly with the same credential. The strange point is that I can not see the request hitting the API (no log) and my code return the "The operation has timed out" which I guess is translated by the 503 code. Again removing the POST parameters the same code works fine (200 OK).

Comment: Have checked the requests going to the API with something like Fiddler to check if there is any difference between Postman and the browser?

Comment: Thanks @phuzi, yes, I did mention that I compared both requests using Fiddler. 
I have now found the issue : The header included by default the "Expect: 100-continue" code, by removing it "request.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;" it now works :-) Thanks!